View creation faster with LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than INNER JOIN
I have a view (supplied by software vendors) that join an asset master table with a table that contains descriptions for various codes in the asset master table.
In the master table there are codes for things such as status, type, function, measure, condition, department etc (the code table is joined 9 times in total)
These descriptions for these codes are all stored in the one code table that essentially only uses 3 columns (there are more columns but they are either null or not relevant)
the Three columns are code_type, code_number and code description. There is a single index on the code table  of Code_type and Code_number
The view as supplied uses Inner Joins on three of the links to the code table, and LEFT OUTER on the others (I assume whoever wrote it was intending to use inner joins on the mandatory codes in the master and LEFT OUTER for the others, they actually used OUTER on some of the mandatory ones also) They are all formatted like
LEFT OUTER JOIN code_table AS typ_dsc ON typ_dsc.code_type = 'master.typ_cde' AND typ_dsc.code_number = master.typ_cde 

The Code table has > 500,000 records, over 480,000 are of code_types not used in this view
A SELECT * from the view fails to return any values after running for an hour or more.
However if I change the three INNER JOINS to LEFT OUTER JOINS it returns all the records (> 160,000) in just over 1 minute
Why is this so ?

Maybe your tables are not indexed properly.

And please provide what DBMS you're using. There are dozens of them and they all behave differently.

Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for the two queries

Sorry, I am using sql server (sorry, not sure what version) and as a humble accountant I dont get permissions to run EXPLAIN PLANS or anything like that (I am lucky to get read permission on database)
